# Updating attributes in a MySQL database via a java servlet and html

Tags: java, html, servlets

I'm trying to figure out how to update attributes in a database table via an html page as well as a java servlet.

First, I have a form that has 3 text boxes.  I have no idea how to connect the methods in the below code to these.

```
    <form name="FrmBird" id="frmBird" method="post" action="updatebird.java">

                Enter birdID you wish to modify:
                <input type="text" id="txtBird" name="txtBird" value=""/> </br> </br>


                Bird Common name (String):
                <input type="text" id="txtBird1" name="txtBird1" value=""/> </br>
                Bird Scientific name (String):
                <input type="text" id="txtBird2" name="txtBird2" value=""/> </br>
                IUCN Listing (String):
                <input type="text" id="txtBird3" name="txtBird3" value=""/> </br>
                <input type="submit" name="btnSumbit" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit"/>             
    </form>
```

This is the method I created in my java servlet, Bird.java.  It takes a string parameter that goes into a database and updates a field based on a primary key (birdID)

```
    public void updateiucnListing(String iucnListing){
    String sql = "UPDATE birds SET iucnListing = '" + iucnListing + " WHERE birdID = " + this.birdID;
    System.out.println(sql);
    DbUtilities db = new DbUtilities();
    db.executeQuery(sql);
    }
```

This is the instance of the class that I pass the parameter into. updatebirds.java

```
 Bird bird200 = new Bird(200);
 bird200.updateiucnListing("LC");
```

Do I need to make methods for all my attributes in my database?  Or can I make one method that handles everything?

Am I even on the right track here?

Comment: Off-topic comment but: it seems that your code has SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: This is actually for a class and since we're just getting to close the middle of the semester, we haven't even begun to think about security yet.

Comment: If your professor hasn't taught you security and its importance from day one: RUN!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you're connecting to an actual database. I would take a look at the examples in [JDBI](http://jdbi.org/), and consider using JDBI for your SQL needs.

As others have mentioned, you should validate and sanitize any input you take from the HTTP request.

In terms of accessing your form parameters from your servlet, that happens via HTTP. When you click "submit" in your form, the form parameters are sent to the server as part of the HTTP request body. The Servlet API takes care of converting this body into an HttpServletRequest object. Your servlet should have some code like this:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {

   String txtBird = req.getParameter("txtBird1");
   // db code here....
```

This is the most basic way to do it. Your servlet can also have a "doGet" method, to handle GET requests.

Comment: I purposely left out the database credentials and information for this reason.  The connection code was provided by our professor, so we can assume that it's correct and working.  I'm trying to focus on the html part of the application and it's connection to java.

Comment: ok. I added some code that shows how to get the form elements.

Answer (score 0):

There are two common ways of handling updating an object's properties in the database that I've seen.

1) Do it in the setters:

```
private int id;
private String property1;

public void setProperty1(String property1) {
    String sql = "UPDATE bird SET property1 = ? WHERE id = ?);
    //bind local parameter, execute SQL
}
```

2) Allow client code to do multiple set statements, then batch the SQL update.

```
private int id;
private String property1;
private String property2;

public void setProperty1(String property1) {
    this.property1 = property1;
}

public void setProperty2(String property2) {
    this.property2 = property2;
} 

public void commit() {
     String SQL = "UPDATE bird SET property1 = ?, property2 = ? WHERE id = ?";
     //bind member variables, exectute SQL
}
```

Example usage of point 2:

```
Bird b = new Bird();
b.setProperty1("one");
b.setProperty2("two");
b.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

agree with @Pshemo .Here is one solution a generic call you pass the field to be updated and the corresponding value

```
  public void updatefield(String field,String value,String birdID){
String sql = "UPDATE birds SET "+field +"'= '" + value+ " WHERE birdID = "   + this.birdID;
System.out.println(sql);
DbUtilities db = new DbUtilities();
db.executeQuery(sql);
}
```

so you can call from servlet 
Dbuitl.updatefield("iucnListing","TADAA!!" );

or replace field1/2... with actual field names

```
public void updateBird(String value1,String value2,String id )
{ String sql = "UPDATE birds SET  field1'= '" + value1+ "+field2'= '" + value2+ " WHERE birdID = "   + this.birdID;
 DbUtilities db = new DbUtilities();
db.executeQuery(sql);
}
```